# Is it possible to access methods of generic type in an interface class?

Tags: java

I'd like to add a new method to a class by implementing an interface class but without having the need to override it every time. I know that this sounds absurd, but consider the following example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
        subclass.println("Hello");
        subclass.print("World!");
    }

    static abstract class Abstract {
        abstract void print(String message);
    }

    /**
     * I would like to add methods from this class to
     * whatever class that is a subclass of Abstract.
     */
    interface Interface<T extends Abstract> {
        default void println(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    static class Subclass extends Abstract implements Interface<Subclass> {
        @Override
        public void print(String message) {
            System.out.print(message);
        }
    }

}
```

So basically, I want to add the method `println` from `Interface` to any class that extends the class `Abstract`. In this way, we somehow know what type of `T` is. But what I really want to do inside `println` is to call a method from `T` which inherited from the class `Abstract`. Something like:

```
interface Interface<T extends Abstract> {
    default void println(String message) {
        // I know that this WON'T work
        ((Abstract) T).print(message + "\n");
    }
}
```

My reason for this is, to make these methods reusable in a sense that it doesn't need to be overridden (and to save repeated lines of code). I know that it was absurd as it actually sound like the *literal* usage of an abstract class, the only difference is, we cannot extend from multiple classes. Anyway, this is just my conclusion.

So, is this possible? *OR* can it be done in a whole different way rather than using interface? Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you add `println` to `Abstract` ?

Comment: Why can't you simply add the `println` method to the `Abstract` class?

Comment: The thing is, the `Abstract` (for example) was an internal API, we can't modify it and what if the `Subclass` really depends on it. That's why I thought of using an interface for that...

Comment: Oh, I guess you're talking about [extension methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method). Java does not support them.

Comment: @khelwood I see, thank you. This was all just my thought.

Comment: @khelwood But if possible and if there's any chance... can it be done in a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a method in your interface `Interface` to assume that it is on a type extending `Abstract` and call an `Abstract` method, this should work:

```
interface Interface {
    default void println(String message) {
        ((Abstract) this).print(message + "\n");
    }
}
```

That's assuming that you only implement the interface on a class that extends `Abstract`. If you try and call `println()` from an object that doesn't extend `Abstract`, you'll get a casting exception.

Comment: Damn, I was over thinking things like this. Thank you so much!

Comment: So to actually deal with cast exception (and to make it safe), I can just add the generic type parameter: `interface Interface<T extends Abstract>`, then call the method with: `default void println(String message) { ((T) this).print(message + "\n"); }`. Much shorter isn't it? Thanks again! :'>

Comment: @Küroro That doesn't make it any safer, but do as you wish.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong. I definitely don't recommend it at all, but it'll work anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is inconsistent.
All `Interface` objects are not  `Abstract` instances.
Yes you can declare an `Abstract` class that implements `Interface` but you can also declare a `Foo` class that also implements `Interface`.

So casting `this` to `Abstract` is really not a good idea and will just trigger a `ClassCastException` at runtime if `this` is not an `Abstract` instance :

```
default void println(String message) {
    // I know that this WON'T work
    ((Abstract) this).print(message + "\n");
}
```

In fact to achieve your requirement :

> I'd like to add a new method to a class by implementing an interface
>   class but without having the need to override it every time.

you just need a thing : an interface that defines both the method to implement and the default method :

```
interface Interface {
    default void println(String message) {
         this.print(message + "\n");
    }
    void print(String message);
}
```

The subclasses will define just the `print()` method :

```
static class Subclass implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void print(String message) {
        System.out.print(message + " subclass way");
    }
}

static class OtherSubclass implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void print(String message) {
        System.out.print(message + " otherSubclass way");
    }
}
```

And you can use this in this way :

```
Interface subclass = new Subclass();
subclass.println("Hello");
subclass.print("World!");

Interface otherSubclass = new OtherSubclass();
otherSubclass.println("Hello");
otherSubclass.print("World!");
```

The abstract class appears helpless.